# Make sure enumerate* at the beginning of a line

Tags: enumitem

I am using the inline list environment `enumerate*` provided by the package `enumitem`.
But I don't want the environment stay at the same line with previous texts.

If there exist some texts before items, I hope the result can look like the following.

```
some text before items.
1. item 2. item
```

In this case, the following codes works well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{before=\newline}
\begin{document}
some text before items.
\begin{enumerate*}
  \item item
  \item item
\end{enumerate*}
%\par\begin{enumerate*}
%  \item item
%  \item item
%\end{enumerate*}
\end{document}
```

But if the `enumerate*` at the start of a paragraph (see the commented codes in the above), it will produce an error `There's no line here to end`.
How to avoid this error?

Any suggestions or comments are welcome. Thank you very much!

Comment: Try `\begin{enumerate*}[before=\mbox{}]`.

Comment: No errors whith your code !

Comment: @Santoro I mean when remove the comment symbol `%` in the code, there will be an error.

Comment: @Bernard Do you mean use the option `before=\mbox{}` for `enumerate*` manually, when it appears at the beginning of a paragraph? This is a choice. But, maybe there are some methods which can deal with this case no matter whether `enumerate*` is at the beginning of a paragraph.

Comment: @jiaopjie:  You can set it for all enumerate* environments or use the option locally, if you don't have many such environments at the beginning of a paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.
It works well to insert `\noindent\par` at the beginning of `enumerate*` environment.
Since the option `before=...` can't include a `\par` command,
I use `\AtBeginEnvironment` command provided by the `etoolbox` package.

In this case, it works well even if it is after a `paragraph` command, but I don't know why.

The complete code is the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{enumerate*}{\noindent\par\noindent}
\begin{document}
something
\begin{enumerate*}
  \item item
  \item item
\end{enumerate*}
\par
\begin{enumerate*}
  \item item
  \item item
\end{enumerate*}
\paragraph{something}
\begin{enumerate*}
  \item item
  \item item
\end{enumerate*}
\end{document}
```